# Having trouble with this Calculus word problem involving Demand, Cost, Revenue, Profit

Tags: calculus, economics

The 2 variables are messing with my head. Please help me make sense of this? I can't even get it set up right and I'm ready to throw my notebook out a window. Thanks in advance! Problem below:

---

The demand x for a certain product can be modeled by x = 100e^-0.02p per week.

The cost of supplying each unit is $25.

a) Write the PROFIT function as a **function of price p**

b) What is price p at which the maximum profit is realized?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demand $x$ is a function of the price $p$: $$x = 100e^{-0.02}p$$  The profit per item is the price less the cost: $p-25$ and $x$ items are sold.  Can you continue from here?

Comment: ok, so Profit = x(p-25), or (100e^-002p)(p-25) ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  You need to put `$` signs around the MathJax for the formatting commands to take effect.  Take a look at how I edited your question.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I was a bit brain fried, it looks obvious to me now. Part b I found the derivative and critical number to determine the max profit.